# SQL/ORACLE Filtrar registros ativos no mês

Tags: sql, query, oracle, data

Tenho uma tabela que grava meus registros onde uma coluna grava a `data_inicial` e outra coluna a `data_final`.

Preciso gerar um relatório onde o usuário pesquisa todos os registros que estavam entre o o período de por exemplo 01/03/2017 a 31/03/2017.

O que eu precisava é pegar os registros que mesmo tendo iniciado antes desse período ocuparam dias no meu mês 03. Se eu uso por exemplo `data_inicial between 01/03/2017 and 31/03/2017`, os meus registros que tinham data inicial 27/02/2017 e data final 01/04/2017 não aparecem.

Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Olá Matheus, considere aceitar minha resposta se ela lhe foi útil. Se achar que ela está incompleta ou não te atende, faça os devidos comentários para que eu possa melhorá-la.

Answer (score 2):

O `between` não vai permitir porque ele é direto: Somente os registros do dia 01/03/2017 ATÉ 31/03/2017 inclusive serão retornados.

Para considerar **TAMBÉM** os períodos que contém o mês 03, terá que incluir a cláusula `OR` indicando que quer os menores e ao mesmo tempo, maiores que o mês 03.

Todos os registros que pelo menos iniciaram antes do dia 31/03 e que terminaram depois.

```
select * from teste
where dataInicial between '01/03/2017' and '31/03/2017'
      or (dataInicial < '01/03/2017' and dataFinal > '31/03/2017')
```

Neste caso, irá considerar também os que pelo menos terminaram dentro do mês 03

```
select * from teste
where dataInicial between '01/03/2017' and '31/03/2017'
      or (dataInicial < '01/03/2017' and dataFinal >= '01/03/2017')
```